# What is the best between using resolve or waiting to get the page to call controller in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm used to both methods but what I noticed is that when you are using resolve in your route to load data, the page won't displayed until the data are fetched. The user can then be waiting and wondering if he has really clicked.

On the other hand when we make the call in the controller as in this capture, the user can go to the page but wait for the data (with a spinner showing...)

My question is, what are the advantages/disadvantages of both methods and some tips that can fasten data loading in angular js especially mobile oriented (ionic framework)

[image]

Comment: I think this question might stand a better chance of staying open/getting answered if you rephrase it in terms of advantages/disadvantages/differences. "The best" is completely subjective.

Comment: Also, this is much more a user experience question not a technical one. There aren't many other options that I'm aware of.

Comment: @JoeClay I think you're right ! I'm editing so.